# Laravel sanctum token still working after removing it in some routes in live server?

Tags: php, laravel, api, token, laravel-sanctum

I'm using laravel sanctum to create API, it works fine in localhost but in live server there is an issue:

- when access route under middleware like this:

  ```
    Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth:sanctum'], function(){

    Route::get('/test-middleware',function(){
        return "test- middleware";
    });

  });
  ```

it return json "Unauthenticated", I generate an access token successfully and pass it in postman bearer token, it allow to visit this route successfully and return:

```
test- middleware
```

**the issue is:**

when I remove the access token of this user from database directly or from logout function like:

```
auth()->user()->tokens()->delete();
```

it supposed return "Unauthenticated", cuz there is no token for this user, but when access this route again with the removed token, it still allow user to access:

```
test- middleware
```

although I removed this user's token from database, I checked the endpoint in different api tester and show the same output?!.

**Users model:**

```
    class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;
```

**Kernel: Http/Kernel**

```
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
         \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
        'throttle:api',
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
];
```

**public/.haccess:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.+)$
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    
    # Handle Authorization Header

    
    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**sanctum: Config/sanctum:**

```
    <?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Stateful Domains
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Requests from the following domains / hosts will receive stateful API
    | authentication cookies. Typically, these should include your local
    | and production domains which access your API via a frontend SPA.
    |
    */

    'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
        '%s%s',
        'localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1',
        env('APP_URL') ? ','.parse_url(env('APP_URL'), PHP_URL_HOST) : ''
    ))),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sanctum Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This array contains the authentication guards that will be checked when
    | Sanctum is trying to authenticate a request. If none of these guards
    | are able to authenticate the request, Sanctum will use the bearer
    | token that's present on an incoming request for authentication.
    |
    */

    'guard' => ['web'],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Expiration Minutes
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value controls the number of minutes until an issued token will be
    | considered expired. If this value is null, personal access tokens do
    | not expire. This won't tweak the lifetime of first-party sessions.
    |
    */

    'expiration' => null,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sanctum Middleware
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When authenticating your first-party SPA with Sanctum you may need to
    | customize some of the middleware Sanctum uses while processing the
    | request. You may change the middleware listed below as required.
    |
    */

    'middleware' => [
        'verify_csrf_token' => App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        'encrypt_cookies' => App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    ],

];
```

please any help
is there any issues in laravel sanctum in live server?!

Comment: the authentication is only for this route `/test-middleware` is this happen with this route?

Comment: no I made api resource routes like:
    Route::apiResource('cards',CardController::class);
and works

Comment: when make any route like (test-middleware) the issue shows

Comment: because this middleware `['middleware'=>'auth:sanctum']`  or put the api code and what you want

Comment: the problem that token still working although i removed it from database

Answer (score 0):

try this in `logout` function
instead of `auth()->user()->tokens()->delete();`

```
    public function logout(Request $request)
{
    $request->user()->tokens()->delete();
    return  response()->json([
        'message' => 'token deleted successfully'
    ]);
}
```

define this in the top `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

Comment: Thanks for your answer I'll try it

Comment: still the same problem